# Testing Firebase Database with an in-memory fake/db

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

Is there any in-memory implementation for Firebase database for testing Android client logic and integration? I have seen node.js fakes but could not find anything in java. I am not looking for a plain mock which is only good for basic unit-testing.

Comment: why the negative vote?

Answer (score -3):

You must do refactoring your application, and implement an architectural approach. For example, such as MVP, MVVM, Clean, etc. The main thing is the layers. In this case, you can test these layers independently of each other using mock objects.

On the Internet you will find a lot of documentation on this topic,
eg [Essential Guide For Designing Your Android App Architecture](https://blog.mindorks.com/essential-guide-for-designing-your-android-app-architecture-mvp-part-1-74efaf1cda40),
[Why to choose MVVM over MVP — Android Architecture](https://android.jlelse.eu/why-to-choose-mvvm-over-mvp-android-architecture-33c0f2de5516) and many others.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19944143)

Comment: @zeh there is no other way, as far as I know. Well, or get a job in google

Comment: This is not really an answer. Your architectural approaches will not give me what I am looking for. Yes ideally Google should have provided a fake for testing itself. Your comment answers my question better than your answer.

Comment: @adarsh Think that today you need Firebase, tomorrow, you may need a local sqlite database for caching, and the day after tomorrow - Firestore instead of Firebase. Applying an architectural approach, you can test all this. And yes, it will take time to study.

Comment: @tim4dev Sir I know that well, I am not looking for unit-testing, as I have mentioned in the question itself. This is integration-testing.

Comment: @adarsh I meant any kind of testing (unit, instrumental, integration, with UI, without UI, etc).

Comment: @timdev and how do you test integration with firebase?